# Read Excel dynamically and store it in map

Tags: java, excel, dictionary

My requirement is to read the excel dynamically and store the contents in Map. The headers should be key and the respective column should be value so that when I pass the key, I can get the cell value.

My Excel sheet contains multiple rows and columns which can be changed dynamically. My intention is to write a common function in java to read an excel and store the contents in map. The Key should be column headers and the value should be respective cell value of the header. So while retrieving when I pass the header key, I should receive the respective cell value. My plan is to pass the row number and the key in a method so that it can retrieve the respective cell value related to the row as well as the key

```
static Map<String> excelMap = new LinkedHashMap<String>();

public static String readWriteExcel(String sheetName) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException, JSONException
{
    File file = new File("File Path");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream( file );
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create( inputStream );

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet( sheetName );

    int rowNumber =0;
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum(); 
    for(int i=1;i<=rowCount;i++){
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int j=0;j<row.getLastCellNum();j++) {
            String key=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            String value=sheet.getRow(rowNumber+1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            excelMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the excel issue you have?

Comment: Upvote for declaring possible Exceptions that can be thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code, i am assuming the issues: Multiple rows present in the sheet, but you are getting data of first row only.

Solution :
First of all, you need to store all rows data in a List of Map. where list index corresponds to the row number. Also You are not incrementing the rowNumber variable anywhere. Its always 0.
Why not directly use the variable i to get a particular row from sheet?

I think this should work.

```
static List<Map<String, String>> excelData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public static String readWriteExcel(String sheetName) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException, JSONException
{
    File file = new File("File Path");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream( file );
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create( inputStream );

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet( "sheetName" );
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum(); 
    for(int i=1;i<=rowCount;i++){
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        Map<String,String> rowData = new HashMap<>();
        for(int j=0;j<row.getLastCellNum();j++) {
            String key=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            String value=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            rowData.put(key, value);
        }
        excelData.add(rowData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to map multiple rows you have to store multiple rows.

One way is storing a map consisting column->list containing values for each row.

Another way is storing a map consisting column+row number->value.

Sample code for second method:

```
static Map<String, String> excelMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
...
// storing values
excelMap.put(key + "_" + i, value); // i is row index
...
// getting values
public static String getCellValue(String cellName, int rowIndex) {
    return excelMap.get(cellName + "_" + rowIndex);
}
```